# Get list of network printers silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I want to get the list of network printers through silverlight. I have seen a few examples of using WMI, but they are not available in Silverlight, so, I was wondering if there are any alternatives to find network printers through silverlight or at least the installed printers...

There is also a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667253/getting-a-list-of-local-printers-silverlight-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Silverlight 5, you can use EnumPrinters Win32 API call through PInvoke. The code is pretty long, so I put together a sample that shows how to enumerate the printers on the machine.

http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/27/enumerating-printers-using-pinvoke-in-silverlight-5

With Silverlight 4, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the post @Pete. If there is a work around for Silverlight4 kindly tell me, coz we are not in a position to switch to Silverlight5 right now, specially while it is not even in its Beta stage...

Comment: The link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

Its my understanding that you cannot do this. You don't have the control over this, it is simply handed off for its built in support. This is the same reason why you can't specify a printer - it just doesn't allow this.

Comment: We've all been wrong before - certainty can be an illusion :)