# retrieve the name of the printer with silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, printing

I created a print soft with silverlight. I must verify on which printer my customer prints her document. But I don't find the way to access to the name of the printer after the customer have chose it.

I use this code to initialize the impression

```
printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.PrintPage += OnPrint;
printDoc.EndPrint += EndPrint;
printDoc.BeginPrint += BeginPrint;

printDoc.Print("Badge");
```

I just want cancel the print if the customer choose the bad printer. Is there a way for this? (I know the print functions in Silverlight are very light)

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, but you can through PInvoke: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573672/get-list-of-network-printers-silverlight